# GitLab CI Pipeline not triggered for events on default branch

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I got two branches in my GitLab repo (uat and production). Two deploy jobs are meant to deploy a branch to a specific environment. There are two gitlab-ci.yml files, one in each branch (with the config for that branch) and production is my default branch.
The jobs should run only if files in dir/ changed and not for scheduled pipelines.

**Problem:** The deploy job for UAT is just working as expected: it runs if I push directly to the branch or if I accept a merge request. However, although there is no difference except the branch, the deploy job for production is not triggered on any event.

**Question:** Do you know if I misunderstood something and what would fix this?

Thanks!

- gitlab-ci.yml in `production`

```
deploy_to_production:
  only: 
    refs:
      - production
    changes:
      - dir/*
  except: 
    - schedules

script:
    # upload to prod
```

gitlab-ci.yml in `uat`

```
deploy_to_uat:
  only: 
    refs:
      - uat
    changes:
      - dir/*
  except: 
    - schedules

script:
    # upload to uat
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have those empty lines before `script:` in your file?

This will define `script` under `default`, because it is not tied to a job.

```yaml
default:
  script:
    # upload to uat
```

The reason that it is only running uat is that on the second reference the first one gets overwritten. You can check this on gitlab on your project page under CI/CD/Editor.

And here you can view the final yaml after merging:
[image]